# can I use a vector<string> with value-parametrized googletest

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to parameterize a directory, means every file from a directory [the directory structure with two empty json and two empty cfg files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzNca.png) should be processed by a parametrized TEST_P. Is this possible?

Unfortunately I got an error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -L/opt/gtest/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread -I./ -I../../src -I/opt/gtest/include -o test2  parametrized2.cpp
parametrized2.cpp: In function 'testing::internal::ParamGenerator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > gtest_ParametrizedGTestInstanceParametrizedGTest_EvalGenerator_()':
parametrized2.cpp:57:5: error: could not convert 'testing::ValuesIn(const Container&) [with Container = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >; typename Container::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]()' from 'testing::internal::ParamGenerator<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'testing::internal::ParamGenerator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >'
make: ***
```

Whats my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> jsonCfgFiles;

//opening any folder and saving all file-names in a vector<string>
std::vector<string> openDir(string path)
{
  DIR* dir;
  dirent* pdir;
  vector<string> files;
  dir = opendir(path.c_str());
  while (pdir = readdir(dir)) {
     files.push_back(pdir->d_name);
  }
  return files;
}

vector<string> GetJsonCofigFiles(void)
{
  vector<string> f;
  std::vector<std::string> jsonCfgFilesLocal;
  string buffer = "";
  f = openDir("oem"); // pass which dir to open

  // collect only json files
  for (auto i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); ++i) {
     if ((*i).find(".json") != std::string::npos) {
        buffer = "" + (*i);
        jsonCfgFiles.push_back(buffer);
     }
  }
  return jsonCfgFilesLocal;
}
// Using just string compiles well. Why is vector<string> not possible?
class ParametrizedGTest : public testing::TestWithParam<vector<string> > {
public:
  ParametrizedGTest();
  virtual ~ParametrizedGTest();
};

ParametrizedGTest::ParametrizedGTest()
{
}

ParametrizedGTest::~ParametrizedGTest()
{
}

TEST_P(ParametrizedGTest, testParameter)
{
  cout << (*(GetParam().begin())) << "," << endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ParametrizedGTestInstance,
                      ParametrizedGTest,
                      ::testing::ValuesIn(jsonCfgFiles));

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  jsonCfgFiles = GetJsonCofigFiles();
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Thanks to Marko Popovic now I solved this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> jsonCfgFiles;

std::vector<string> open1(string path) //opening any folder and saving all file-names in a vector<string>
{
   DIR* dir;
   dirent* pdir;
   vector<string> files;
   dir = opendir(path.c_str());
   while (pdir = readdir(dir)) {
      files.push_back(pdir->d_name);
   }
   return files;
}

std::vector<string> GetJsonCofigFiles(void)
{
   vector<string> f;
   string buffer = "";
   std::vector<std::string> jsonCfgFiles;
   f = open1("oem"); // pass which dir to open
   for (auto i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); ++i) {
      if ((*i).find(".json") != std::string::npos) {
         buffer = "oem/" + (*i);
         jsonCfgFiles.push_back(buffer);
      }
   }
   return jsonCfgFiles;
}

class ParametrizedGTest : public testing::TestWithParam<string> {
public:
  ParametrizedGTest();
  virtual ~ParametrizedGTest();
};

ParametrizedGTest::ParametrizedGTest()
{
}

ParametrizedGTest::~ParametrizedGTest()
{
}

TEST_P(ParametrizedGTest, testParameter)
{
  cout << GetParam() << endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ParametrizedGTestInstance,
                      ParametrizedGTest,
                      ::testing::ValuesIn(jsonCfgFiles));

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  jsonCfgFiles = GetJsonCofigFiles();
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

When compiled and run

```
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest
[ RUN      ] ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest.testParameter/0
oem/_PVO111k_.json
[       OK ] ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest.testParameter/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest.testParameter/1
oem/_PVO112k.json
[       OK ] ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest.testParameter/1 (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from ParametrizedGTestInstance/ParametrizedGTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the template argument that you are giving to class `testing::TestWithParam`. The documentation states that template parameter "T is the type of your parameter values". Since you are trying to create tests parameterized by paths to *json* files, the type you want for your case is `std::string`, not `std::vector<std::string>`. Change line

```
class ParametrizedGTest : public testing::TestWithParam<vector<string> > {
```

to

```
class ParametrizedGTest : public testing::TestWithParam<string> {
```

and the code will compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it compiles with string well. Unfortanately when I run this no test case will be executed: "Running 0 tests from 0 test cases"

Comment: @jejej The tests are instantiated during compilation. This means that you can't load file paths during program execution but you need to create a list of dummy paths that will be used. Try something like this: `std::vector<std::string> jsonCfgFiles{ "path1", "path2" };`. You should not be writing unit tests that depend on the current state of the environment anyway. Unit tests should be completely isolated from the environment.

Comment: The tests need to read the json file content. Only here the json files are empty dummy files. Unfortunately there is no other way.

Comment: @jejej Then you can't use value parameterized tests from googletest. This is a **unit testing framework** and unit tests do not rely on existence of files on the filesystem. If you are writing tests like that, you should consider using some other testing tool/framework. You could write a script that loads the json files and have it insert necessary strings in the `cpp` file where the `jsonCfgFiles` is initialized. You would then run this script before you compile the test program, but this is an ugly hack. As I said, if you want to do that, you should consider using something other than gtest.

Comment: Should I write the file content in source files and compile?